# Getting create_sql_chain to work for gpt 4

Tags: openai-api, langchain

The current code I have below works when I use gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct however when I use gpt-4 it doesn't work. I like using this framework because i care about getting only sql code back which the other agents don't do. How do I change it so that I can use other gpt models.

```
from langchain.chains import create_sql_query_chain
connection_string = ""
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(connection_string)
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, verbose=True, model='gpt-4')

seed_prompt = """
Given an input question, create a syntactically correct MySQL SQL query to run.

Question: "Question here"
SQLQuery: "SQL Query to run"

"""

restrictions = """
Never use LIMIT statement, use TOP statement instead.
Format all numeric response ###,###,###,###.
Only return relevant columns to the question.
If a table or column does not exist, return table or column could not be found.
Question: {input}
"""

prompt = seed_prompt + restrictions
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["input"], template=prompt
)

database_chain = create_sql_query_chain(llm,db, prompt=PROMPT)
sql_query = database_chain.invoke({"question": x})
print(sql_query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JK found a resolution! Changed OpenAI to ChatOpenAI and it did the trick

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).